# How to setup a guest network?

Tags: networking, access-point

i've a some Cisco WAP2000 access point. 
These are used to allow our employee and our warehouse to connect to out network. 
I would like to allow guest's to connect but for using only internet, with no limitations, and hide our disks, printers etc.. 
I know this access point allow multiple SSID but  i don't know how to use this feature to create a guest network.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not fammiliar with Cisco WAP access points, but a you should be able to configure two SSIDs, each in its own VLAN. So you just create a 'guest' VLAN for them.

After that, you just need to set up access policies on the router/firewall, to only allow connections from the guest subnet to the internet, and dissalow connections to other parts of the network. Also it would be smart to enable logging in case of abuse (depends on your local laws what you have to log, and what not).